# Using CSS, trying to center and align multiple tables side by side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header bar in which I'm trying to create 3 sections: Left, Center, Right.

All content has to center vertically and be backwards compatible with IE7, that's why I'm using tables, unless you have an easier solution.

As you can see right now, the center content tables are stacking. How can I style it so that the tables are aligned side-by-side?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/35/

UPDATE: I tried one suggestion. The tables are side-by-side now, but you'll notice it's still not quite right when 1 of the tables is highlighted, the formatting is off. I also need the highlighted blue content to fill the container exactly.

UPDATE2: Ok, I just realized part of the problem. My browser is zoomed in 125%...there isn't actually a 1 pixel space between the container and the bottom when I zoom out.

UPDATE3: Paul provided a solution that works for me. I appreciate all the suggestions.

```
.container{
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: none;
    position: fixed;
}
table {
    height: 50px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
td {
    padding: 0px;
}

.cell-left {
    float:left;
}
.cell-selected {
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
.cell-right {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    right:0px;
}

<div class='container'>
    <div class='cell-left'>
        <table class='cell cell-selected'><tr><td>
            LEFT
        </td></tr></table>
    </div>
<center>
<table class='cell'><tr>
<td><table class='cell cell-selected'><tr><td>CENTER1</td></tr></table></td>
<td><table class='cell'><tr><td>CENTER2</td></tr></table></td>
<td><table class='cell'><tr><td>CENTER3</td></tr></table></td>
</tr></table> 
</center>
    <div class='cell-right'>
        <table class='cell'><tr><td>
            RIGHT
        </td></tr></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated. If you wanted to do this using tables, the three columns would all be part of the same table. Have you tried searching online for a [3 column layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm)?

Comment: A bit of javascript is possible or only html/css ?

Comment: Possibly, though I'd prefer CSS. What's possible with javascript that can't be styled initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The floating divs for the center table are missing, shouldn't it be:

```
<div  class='cell-left'><table class='cell'><tr><td>
        CENTER1
    </td></tr></table></div>
    <table class='cell'><tr><td>
        CENTER2
    </td></tr></table>
    <div  class='cell-right'><table class='cell'><tr><td>
        CENTER3
    </td></tr></table></div>
```

But regardless of that, why not use one table for each level of structure instead of tables for each element.

See ***[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/5/)*** for stacked tables.

See [***DEMO 2***](http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/7/) for nested tables.

See ***[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/21/)*** for nested tables with highlight features (try hover!).

See ***[DEMO 4](http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/29/)*** for equal heights of all cells.

See [***DEMO 5***](http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/36/) for adjusted widths of far left and far right cell and center cells spanning everything in between.

See [***DEMO 6***](http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/37/) for adjusted widths of far left and far right cell and center cells are as small as possible.

Comment: I don't know what that is. You have 2 header bars, I need 1 with centered content containing the 3 containers (tables)

Comment: See second demo, is that what you want? (colors only for illustrating purpose)

Comment: yea, I see what you mean, but that won't work for me. I need to be able to highlight (background-color) a container and have it fully highlight the cell. See my updated demo above...that's still not quite right.

Comment: can you make 'level2' fill the entire container top to bottom?

Comment: First, the highlighting, see DEMO 3.

Comment: DEMO 4 is the same as #3 but with equal heights (cellpadding/cellspacing=0).

Comment: Well, see DEMO 5 for adjusted width.

Comment: Thanks. Although I don't want the center content to size dynamically, your suggestions did get me to the solution. Appreciate the help.

Comment: See DEMO 6 for center cells not spanning available space.

Comment: Just saw your DEMO 6. Interesting...and it works without the "center" tags I had. I think that'll work even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of three tables inside center section use use td tags.

```
<table class='cell'>
  <tr>
    <td>CENTER1</td>
    <td>CENTER2</td>
    <td>CENTER3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[EDIT] version with only one table http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/33/

Comment: Styling for the td's? style="width: 33%; text-align: center;" and perhaps a style="width: 100%" for the table.

Comment: I tried that and updated the jsfiddle. It's still not quite right though. I added highlighting to one table and you can see the formatting is off.

Comment: Add style="margin-top:-6px" to each table with text "CENTER1".

Comment: I edited my answer and added a link to other version. Is it what you needed?

Comment: eiKatte, it's not quite right. I don't want the content to fill dynamically, I need it to be static, see my updated DEMO above.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution without table and with a little bit of JS to set the same height on each column.
The `.before` and `<span class="before"></span>` are here as a substitute of the `:before` (because it doesn't work on IE7)

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/p3tv9n5m/

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='cell cell-left'>
        <span class="before"></span><span class="cell-content">content</span>
    </div>
    <div class='cell cell-center'>
        <span class="before"></span><span class="cell-content">content<br />content<br />content</span>
    </div>
    <div class='cell cell-right'>
        <span class="before"></span><span class="cell-content">content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position:relative;
}
.cell{
    width:33.3333333333333%;
    float:left;
}
.cell .before {
    width:0;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.cell-content {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.cell-left{
    text-align:left;
    background:#ccc;
}
.cell-center{
    text-align:center;
    background:#ddd;
}
.cell-right{
    text-align:right;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cells = $('.cell'),
        cellsLgth = cells.length,
        maxHeight = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < cellsLgth; i++){
        var height = cells.eq(i).height();
        if(height > maxHeight)  maxHeight = height;
    }
    cells.css('height',maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: Just a note: `width:33.3333333333333%;` can cause trouble in IE7 due to rounding errors. Better to use slightly less values.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
white-space: nowrap;
background-color: red;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
text-align:center;
}
table {
width:100%;
border-spacing: 0px;
}

table td {
width:33.3333%;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
}


<div class='container'>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>LEFT</td> 
        <td>CENTER</td>
        <td>RIGHT</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drvn9x26/39/